# jQuery stop and reapeat animation from start

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, delay

I have problem with animation.

Code on click is following:

```
$('.obj p').stop(true, true); 

$('.obj p').css("top", "0" ).delay(3000).animate({top: "-=100%"}, 300, function () {
    $(this).delay(1300).animate({top: "-=100%"}, 300, function () { 
        $(this).delay(2800).animate({top: "-=100%"}, 300);  
    });
});
```

This works great on first click or on click after animatie ends, but when I click on it when animate is workong it starts from begining correctly but delay is broken.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this something you couldn't do better with CSS animation instead of JS?

Comment: Are you supposed to be able to click when the animation is playing? or do you want to disable that?

Comment: I want to start this animation again from begining